# MySQL query nested select issue

Tags: mysql, select, nested, sql-update

What I need is to loop inside Request table and set 1 only those numbers which exits in request table.

```
UPDATE Number SET requested=1 WHERE id=(SELECT numberID FROM Request)
```

Returns error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with JOIN as

```
UPDATE
Number
inner join Request on Request.numberID = Number.id
set Number.requested = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UPDATE Number
SET requested=1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT numberID FROM Request)
```

Please remember, "=" only can connect one value to one value.
In your example, left side of "=" is a value, but on the right side, it is a set of values returned by the subquery.
This is not going to work in database.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
UPDATE Number n, Request r SET n.requested = 1 WHERE n.id = r.numberID
```